# Cannot log in to Drupal site

Tags: 7, users

I have problems with a Drupal 7 site. Sometimes, when I try to log in as non-admin user I am not able to login, despite typing in the correct email and password (I am using the [Email Registration](https://drupal.org/project/email_registration) module). There is no issue with this module because from the very first day after I installed it, it worked well. However, in the last couple of days or week I am getting errors for when I try to login.

I logged in as admin and changed the password for the non-admin user, after doing that, I was again able to login on my site.

I got this error sometimes, but it is not frequent.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Please try to clean up language, it's really hard to read (maybe only to non-native speakers?). What plugin you are talking about? Drupal has modules, and even if it's about a module, please provide name and link to it. And what do you mean by "not logged in"? What message appears? Wrong password, maybe? PHP error?

Comment: Could post the error you are getting?

Comment: I used "Email Registration" module. and it is not giving any error just give red colored textbox of email.

Comment: check link for my error http://rtrial.com/loginerror.png

Comment: where?did you miss mentioning it?

Comment: that is validation, not an error.

Comment: When it is showing ?

Comment: ok When i got this validation error I have to change password from admin. and after changing password I login to site.

Comment: I don't know because of i login with this credentials before couple of hours but suddenly i am not able to login to site with my credential.

Answer (score 1):

The red box you see is a means that the e-mail address you typed in did not match with any e-mail addresses registered on the site, *or* that the password was not recognised.  You should also be able to see a red message-box   further up on the same page with more information about the problem.  For example:

> Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?

The most likely explanation for this error is that you misremembered the password.  This also explains why it starts working again after you login as admin and reset the password for the non-admin user.

However, I've noticed that you've definitively ruled out this explanation in your question. Fair enough, I just wanted you to make *sure* this is not what is happening.  I've run dozen of Drupal sites for many years (many of them with the [Email registration](https://drupal.org/project/email_registration) module enabled) - and I've *never* seen this happen *except* when the credentials are mistyped.

If that is *not* what is happening, I have no good alternative explanation.

To progress with debugging, you may extract the `{users}.pass` field (hashed) from your database, and see if the hashed value changes between when you're able to log in, to when you're not.  If it is changed, then you have some rogue process (or user) that munges the pass field in your `{users}` database.  (If it is *not* changed, then this is very, very mysterious.)

Comment: but my email and password is correct. I am able to login with same credentials before but suddenly it give me error and for error message it not give any error message